# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'male'

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm running the following python script:

```
%%time
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

print(cross_val_scores['DecisionTreeClassifier']['best_params'])

decision_tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(
  random_state=RAND_STATE,
  class_weight='balanced',
  max_depth=3
)


decision_tree.fit(X_train, y_train)

feature_imp = decision_tree.feature_importances_

labels = list(X_train.columns)
plt.barh([x for x in range(len(feature_imp))], feature_imp)
plt.title('DecisionTreeClassifier Feature Importance')
plt.yticks(range(len(labels)), labels)
plt.show()
```

However I got the errors like:

```
{'max_depth': 3}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/tree/_classes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    940             sample_weight=sample_weight,
    941             check_input=check_input,
--> 942             X_idx_sorted=X_idx_sorted,
    943         )
    944         return self

--------3 frames-------
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __array__(self, dtype)
    1991 
    1992     def __array__(self, dtype: NpDtype | None = None) -> np.ndarray:
 -> 1993         return np.asarray(self._values, dtype=dtype)
    1994 
    1995     def __array_wrap__(

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'male'
```

is there someone who can fix it?
I just want to run this but it's not working.

I got the code from the following source: https://www.jcchouinard.com/classification-machine-learning-project-in-scikit-learn/

Answer (score 0):

You probably jump the section "Handle Categorical Data". You have to make a dummy of categorical features (like "sex"), because DecisionTreeClassifier works with numerical types only.

```py
# handle categorical data
cat_cols = X.select_dtypes(include=['object','category']).columns
dummies = pd.get_dummies(X[cat_cols], drop_first=True)
X[dummies.columns] = dummies
X.drop(cat_cols, axis=1, inplace=True)
X.head()
```